# how to transfer data fin session of two different kind of users

Tags: php, session

hello friends im working on a project(online auction type) and there are two different users(Buyers and sellers) and there is a small problem coming is that i cant transfer the data between two different kind of users(between buyer and seller) for eg(my actual problem):-I signed as a buyer and then i can easily go to categories(car,bikes,electronic) and then when i enter into CAR categories i can easily see the list of all the car images of all the sellers; but when i click on any of the car image i cant see the whole details of that individual seller(like on amazon when u click on any product they show u the whole detailsof one product also without losing your own session) . I have use sessions in my php.
my code of 'login.php':-

```
<?php


 session_start();

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect");

 mysql_select_db("form1") or die("could not connect");

 $Email=$_REQUEST['email'];

 $Password=$_REQUEST['pwd'];

 $role=$_REQUEST["category"];

 $_SESSION['un']=$Email;

  if($role=="Bidder")

{

$query="SELECT * from bidder1 WHERE email='".$Email."' and  pwd='".$Password."'"; 

          $mailpwd=mysql_query($query);

           $check=mysql_num_rows($mailpwd);

if($check==1)
{
    header("Location:buyproduct.php");
}
else
{
echo "sorry wrong id or password";}}

else
{
    $query="SELECT * from seller1 WHERE email='".$Email."' and pwd='".$Password."'";
    $mailpwd=mysql_query($query);
    $check=mysql_num_rows($mailpwd);
    if($check==1)
    {
        header("Location:welcomeseller.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong id and password of seller";
    }

}?>
```

/*AFTER THAT I GO TO buyproduct.php */

```
<?php
  session_start();
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect");
   mysql_select_db("form1") or die("could not connect");

  echo '<div class="drpdown">'."welcome"."&nbsp;".$_SESSION['un'].'</div>';?>
```

*/AFTER THAT I SELECT ONE OF THE CATEGORY carcategory.php*/

```
<?php
  session_start();
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect");
   mysql_select_db("form1") or die("could not connect");
   echo $_SESSION['un'];
   echo "<br>";?>
<?php


     $u=$_SESSION['un'];
     $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM seller1 WHERE procategory='Four wheeler'");

   while($show=mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {

       $imagename=$show['proname'];

         $imagepath=$show['proimg'];
        $image="uploads/".$imagepath;
     echo "<div style='display:inline-block;'>
  <a class='container' href='cardetails.php'>
  <img src='".$image."' height='300' width='300'>
 <p style='font-size:25px;text-decoration:none;margin-top:-20px;'>".$imagename."</p></a></div>";


   }
   ?>
```

*/AFTER THAT I WANT TO GO TO cardetails.php
what should i write in it to show whole details of a particular seller with image without losing my session */

Comment: AFTER THAT , you need to create a form with `action='cardetails.php'` and `method='post'` in `carcategory.php` to send data which is not in session, and session value you will get at same server any time untill session lost by its timeout and manually.

Comment: okay i can understand what you are saying but how i can fetch the data in the form from  other database - seller1.  I have used two different database for bidder and seller...and when i come in carcategory.php...i can see all the cars which fetch from database seller1 and wen i click on one particular  car i want to fetch the data of that particular seller on cardetails....please tell me what should i write in form in carcategory .....?

Comment: @Rishi hey i have used this method for image <a class='container' href='cardetails.php?imageName=$image'> and then on cardetails i used get method and imgetting the image on another but i also want details of the photo from database ....what should i write in form by your method?